# Lync 2013 pulls in wrong contacts from Outlook

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I have one user who has their Lync contact list showing wrong user information.

For example, one contact was listed correctly yesterday, but now their name changed to someone outside of the company, but in the users Outlook contact list. When I go into the contact card, it shows information for multiple contacts in the user's Outlook contact list.

How do I clean this up?

[image: Many wrong Outlook contacts]

Comment: Did you ever find the cause for this?

Comment: Nope, it is still doing it too

Comment: Can you double-check if there are any issues with AD replication?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment it might be that Lync got configured with proxy email addresses. This happen sometimes if a person (e.g. Joe Blocks) left the company and the email from Joe is assigned to another person (e.g. Peter Mustermann). Then it might happen that Joe re-apper in the list but if you click on it, an chat with Peter is initialized. There is a [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7c8deb97-fca2-4306-a4fa-4aeeee6204a0/lync-contact-showing-wrong-name-after-new-email-address-was-added-to-the-his-exchange-account?forum=ocsclients) in the Microsoft forum which explains that issue and give you more infos if you need them.